# Slideup on scrolling - close button not satisfactory

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, slideup

I have content that slides up from the bottom of the page when you scroll down a certain amount.

Clicking on a button will close the slide-up.

But the slide-up reappears if you continue scrolling down the page.

How do I make the slide-up disappear once and for all if the close button is clicked just once?

Here is script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
var h = $('#container').height(); 
var y = $(window).scrollTop();

        if( y > (h*.25) ) { 
            $("#btmsUpContainer").slideDown("slow"); 
        } else { 
            $("#btmsUpContainer").slideUp("slow"); 
        } 
}); 

$('.close-it').bind('click', function() {
        $("#btmsUpContainer").slideUp("slow"); 
    return false;
}); 
})
```

Here is CSS:

```
#btmsUpContainer { position: fixed; width: 170px; bottom: 29px; z-index: 7777; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: none; }
#btmsUp { left: 0; width: 170px; margin: 0; }
#btmsUp .close-it { position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 12px; right: 0; z-index: 7778; width: 10px; }
```

Here is page code:

```
<div id="btmsUpContainer">
<div id="btmsUp">

<span class="close-it"><a href="#"><img src="close-it.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 0;"></a></span><br />

This is stuff that appears in the box that slides up.

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `hidden` variable when the user closes the content, and check for it before sliding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var hidden = false; //Initialize the 'hidden' variable to 'false'
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if(!hidden){ //Check if the user has hidden the content
            var h = $('#container').height(); 
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            if( y > (h*.25) ) { 
                $("#btmsUpContainer").slideDown("slow"); 
            } else { 
                $("#btmsUpContainer").slideUp("slow"); 
            } 
        }
    }); 

    $('.close-it').bind('click', function() {
        $("#btmsUpContainer").slideUp("slow");
        hidden = true; //Set the 'hidden' variable to 'true'
        return false;
    }); 
})
```

Comment: DC_ thanks, I really appreciate you spending your time on this. I'm glad the answer was so simple, too!

Comment: @Ethelred You're welcome. If this solution worked for you, consider selecting it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: OK, I'll check the forum once more tomorrow and then select it if there's nothing better.  (Not that I expect anything better!)  I'll put it on my calendar for sure.